# JSON array access - stored in DB

Tags: php

I have stored a JSON string inside the database to prevent there needing to be multiple columns. The 'data' column as seen below contains three strings: external, device and internal.

[image]

I am trying to access the variables but it is not functioning as I expected. The var_dump 
on the data field shows the variables are there to be accessed.

```
var_dump($ImpJson[1]->data);

string(72) "{ "external": "26.5", "device": "2333b23643fc42ee", "internal": "26.9" }"
```

However, when I try an access an individual variable I get an error saying that the variable does not exist:

```
var_dump($ImpJson[1]->data['external']); 

Warning: Illegal string offset '"external"'
```

The only other way I can think of accessing this string is via the range function e.g. 16-19 = external, however, the data I am working with is live data and that is not a consistent fix in the sense that if the device Id changes and contains fewer characters then the entire range values are invalid.

How can I access the variables inside a database that are equal to a JSON string?

```
 function selectImp()
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Imp ORDER BY id DESC";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = array();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($r = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    return  json_encode($rows);


    //Selecting from database
$ImpText = selectImp();
$ImpJson = json_decode($ImpText);
//var_dump($ImpJson);
echo ' <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="articleDiv">';
    for ($i=0 ; $i<1 ; $i++) 
    {
        //var_dump($ImpJson[1]->data);
        var_dump($ImpJson[1]->data['external']); //16-19  34-49  66-69
          /*  echo '<p>'.$ImpJson[$i]->data[16,19].'</p>';
            echo '<p>'.$ImpJson[$i]->date.'</p>';
            echo '<p>'.$ImpJson[$i]->data.'</p>';
        echo '<hr>';*/
    }
echo '</div>';
    }
```

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which can be run by others which shows how you read the data from the database and how you handle the JSON data. You most likely need a `json_decode()` call.

Comment: _hangon:_ in `selectImp()` you `json_encode` first so that you need to decode afterwards? Why not return the plain array `$rows`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest to decode that json already when you fetch the rows:

```
function selectImp() {
   global $conn;
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM Imp ORDER BY id DESC";
   $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute();
   $rows = array();
   $result = $stmt->get_result();
   while($r = $result->fetch_assoc())
   {
      // decode that json already here!
      $r['data'] = json_decode($r['data']); 
      $rows[] = $r;
   }
   return  $rows;  // no need for a json_encode here...
                   // this would have gone messy anyway with a jsonstring inside that..
}

$ImpText = selectImp();
// now you'll find your values here:
$ImpText[0]['data']->external;
```

- `$ImpText` is the array of all rows, so we need `[i]` to access a row
- a row is an array of columns -> `['data']`
- data is an object (according to the json string), so `->external`

So the output would look like that:

```
echo ' <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="articleDiv">';
for ($i=0 ; $i<count($ImpJson) ; $i++) 
{
     echo '<p>'.$ImpText[$i]['data']->external.'</p>';
     echo '<p>'.$ImpText[$i]['data']->device.'</p>';
          // the 'normal' data:
     echo '<p>'.$ImpText[$i]['id'].'</p>';
     echo '<hr>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

Also have a look at the new JSON datatype in mysql: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html
Might be worth thinking about switching to that.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `json_decode` on the JSON string.

```
$data = json_decode($ImpJSON[1]->data);
```

[json_decode](https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.

Comment: I have already decoded the values, check the updated version of the question

Comment: The value of `$ImpJSON` has indeed been converted into a PHP objects, but `$ImpJSON[1]->data` is a string (according to your `var_dump`). Assuming `data` is properly formatted JSON, you should be able to use `json_decode` to make it an object too.

Comment: @NodeCode also, see Jeff's answer for a perhaps more elegant way to essentially do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the json to an array before you can access it like that:

```
$data = json_decode($ImpJson[1], true);
var_dump($data);
echo $data['external']
```